# Python logging format: how to print only the last part of logger name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I'm using python logging with the following format string:

```
'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s - %(message)s'
```

The `%(name)s` part prints the logger name:

```
2017-10-26 13:17:58,019 INFO device_gps.comm.protocol - GPSProtocol(port=COM13) - Starting GPS serial communications (port: COM13)
2017-10-26 13:17:58,022 INFO scs_control.context - Starting component: DeviceGPS
2017-10-26 13:17:58,033 INFO scs_elevation.elevation - Initializing ElevationModel engine instance.
```

Like with other logging facilities (like *log4j*) I'd like to print only the last part of the logger name for brevity (shown in bold in the example above).

This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671409/python-logger-print-child-logger-name-without-parent-name) suggests to change the logger name, but doing so would destroy the parent-child logger relationship, which is really useful to configure logging for a group of loggers.

How can I have python logging print the last part of a logger name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set a filter to set a `LogRecord` attribute to the last part of the logger name, and use that in your format string. For example, running this script:

```
import logging

class LastPartFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.name_last = record.name.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
        return True

logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name_last)s %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
handler.addFilter(LastPartFilter())

logging.getLogger('foo').warning('Watch out - foo!')
logging.getLogger('foo.bar').warning('Watch out - foo.bar!')
logging.getLogger('foo.bar.baz').warning('Watch out - foo.bar.baz!')
```

produces this:

> foo Watch out - foo!
>   bar Watch out - foo.bar!
>   baz Watch out - foo.bar.baz!

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know or realize filters could add fields (rather, formatting strings use the log record as data object for string interpolation). Thanks a lot, you rock!

Comment: @jjmontes Using filters to add fields is documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information

Answer (score 2):

The attributes available for use in logging are listed [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes)

You probably want your format to be `'%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(message)s'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately some of my loggers belong to third party libraries with not-so-meaningful module names. I can set the logger name but not the module name, hence I'm looking to use the last part of the name instead of the module.