# How to leverage the 'logging' module in a library while providing an easy interface to the library users?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I am developping a Python library that defines the following classes:

- a `Controller` class
- a `BaseManager` class and several `BaseManagerXxx` children classes

The `Controller` instanciates managers, then run them (make them do things). A user application using this library will typically implement new classes that inherit from `BaseManagerXxx` classes, instanciates one `Controller` specifying the managers instances to create, and run this controller. An example of minimal code is as follows:

```
#---------------------------------------------------
# Library code
#---------------------------------------------------

class Controller:

    def __init__(self,managerinfo):
        self.managers = [mtype(mname) for mtype,mname in managerinfo]

    def run(self):
        # do something with managers, for instance:
        self.managers[0].parseStuff()
        self.managers[1].cleanStuff()

class BaseManager:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def parseStuff(self):
        pass #something is actually done here
    def cleanStuff(self): # example only
        pass #something is actually done here

class BaseManager1: BaseManager:
    pass # actually redefine some base methods
class BaseManager2: BaseManager:
    pass # actually redefine some base methods
```

A user app code looks like this:

```
#---------------------------------------------------
# User app code
#---------------------------------------------------
from the_library import *
from another_user_module import ARandomClass

class MyManager1: BaseManager1
    def parseStuff(self):
        c = ARandomClass()  #might also log messages or raise exceptions
        print("WARNING: something might be wrong")

class MyManager2: BaseManager2
    def cleanStuff(self):
        raise RuntimeError("Something is seriously wrong here")

c = Controller([
    (MyManager1,"foo"),
    (MyManager2,"bar")])
c.run()
```

For now, logging is done using `print` statements, with strongly heterogenous styles due to custom managers being developped by different users for a same app. I want to leverage the 'logging' module, for consistency, and to apply a common style to all logs done by every part of the app. Moreover, I want all the exceptions to be catched and also result into a log message with the same style.

More precisely:

- Each log must contain the `name` of the manager the execution is currently in (or an empty string if the we are in Controller code); specifically, in the example above, this means that if a log message is for instance emitted in the `ARandomClass`'s constructor, this is still the name of the manager (`foo` in this case) that should be shown.
- All exceptions must be catched and result in a 'CRITICAL' log message (also containing a name as described above)
- In the user app, there should be no more to do for the user than one import statement and one simple statement for each log. Standard exception should be supported (i.e. the users cannot be asked to use only a custom exception).

The only way I found to satisfy those requirements is to use a single logger and to encapsulate, in controller code, all calls to manager methods. Something like this:

```
import logging

class MyLogger:
    pass #some basic logic here using **a single logger** from logging module

class Controller:

    def __init__(self,managerinfo):
        self.logger = MyLogger()
        self.managers = []
        for mtyme,mname in managerinfo:
            self.logger.setName(mname)
            m = mtype(mname)
            self.logger.setName(None)
            self.managers.append(m)

    def run(self):
        # do something with managers, for instance:
        self.logger.setName(self.managers[0].name)
        self.managers[0].parseStuff()
        self.logger.setName(self.managers[1].name)
        self.managers[1].cleanStuff()
        self.logger.setName(None)
```

The exception management would be done redefining `sys.excepthook` and using yet the same logger.

This works, but does not look like the standard way of using the logging module (one logger per module) and I am not very satisfied with the architecture. Actually, there is almost no need to use the logging module with such a pattern (a single class encapsulating `print` would be enough). Would there be a more standard/better way of achieving what I described here?

Comment: You can just `logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__module__ + '.' + self.__class__.__name__)` and assign a logger at the `__init__` of the `Controller` class, so subclasses of the `Controller` will have a standard Python logger with an appropriate name.

Comment: @metatoaster I fail to see how that allows accessing the current manager's `name` *attribute* in order to print it in the log.

Comment: ... Then simply add `self.name` to that `getLogger` argument? The format string allows that to be retrieved, just format it, e.g. [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954855/python-logging-format-how-to-print-only-the-last-part-of-logger-name). The logger name is very much standardized to allow the logging hierarchy to function - I assume that your reference to "the standard way of using the logging module" means that you want to follow the hierarchy - you either follow that to the best of your ability with compromise, or don't, which will result in fights against it.