# In Python 3.7 how to print the log name only if it is not set

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I want to add to the logger format the field %(name)s only if the logger name is set.
So, for example the following code

```
log_main = logging.getLogger()
log1 = logging.getLogger('log1')
log2 = logging.getLogger('log2')
log_main.info('TEXT for main log')
log1.info('TEXT for log 1')
log2.info('TEXT for log 2')
```

will log this. **Notice that the first line doesn't have a name at the beginning.**

```
[INFO] Text for main log
[log1] [INFO] Text for log 1
[log2] [INFO] Text for log 2
```

If I just add the field %(name)s into __FORMAT, id:

```
__FORMAT = { 
    'fmt': '%(name)sXXX %(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] - func=%(funcName)s:[%(lineno)s] - location=%(filename)s - MSG= %(message)s',
    'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    'style': '%'
}
```

The log will print **root** as the log_main logger's name

```
[root] [INFO] Text for main log
[log1] [INFO] Text for log 1
[log2] [INFO] Text for log 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the example from: [Context Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671409/python-logger-print-child-logger-name-without-parent-name)

1) I modified my logger format to look like this.

```
__FORMAT = {
    'fmt': '%(asctime)s%(name)s[%(levelname)s] - func=%(funcName)s:[%(lineno)s] - location=%(filename)s - MSG= %(message)s',
    'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    'style': '%'
}

%(asctime)s%(name)s[%(levelname)s]
```

is used instead of

```
%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]
```

2) I added this new filter

```
class RecordNameFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record) -> bool:
        if record.name == 'root':
            record.name = ' '
        else:
            record.name = f' ({record.name}) '

        return True
```

3) Added the filter to my log's stream handler, e.g.:

```
streamHandler_out.addFilter(RecordNameFilter())
```

This results in a log that looks like this

```
2019-08-20 20:57:50 [INFO] - func=<module>:[37] - location=threading_sat_player.py - MSG= 2019-08-20 20:57:50.869101 : First output
2019-08-20 20:57:50 (A) [INFO] - func=run:[24] - location=my_thread.py - MSG= 2019-08-20 20:57:50.869101 : Start task A in the background
2019-08-20 20:57:50 (B) [INFO] - func=run:[24] - location=my_thread.py - MSG= 2019-08-20 20:57:50.870099 : Start task B in the background
2019-08-20 20:57:50 (C) [INFO] - func=run:[24] - location=my_thread.py - MSG= 2019-08-20 20:57:50.870099 : Start task C in the background
```

The logger name is filtered out if it's "root", otherwise it is printed in (), e.g. (A) etc.